# Can I "up" my question?

Tags: support

What are the ways one could use to make his (old+unanswered) question reappear in some list (Unanswered, active, ...) so that people can see it and maybe answer it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can offer a bounty.

Comment: Editing it will make it appear in the the Active list. However, I would suggest that you only edit if you actually have some relevant information to add. If you clarify the question then naturally people may be more able to answer it

Comment: After I asked this question, I had a new comment on my unanswered question, so maybe this is a new way to up questions... (Just kidding).